# Next/Previous buttons sending to wrong path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want previous/next buttons on my edit screen for each record that send you to the previous/next record ordered by id.

None of the simple solutions I have found online have worked and I can't seem to figure out why.

controller:

```
def edit
    @school = School.find(params[:id])
end
```

model:

```
def previous_school
    School.where(['id < ?', id]).last
end

def next_school
    School.where(['id > ?', id]).first
end
```

view:

```
<%= link_to("Previous School", @school.previous_school) if @school.previous_school %>
<%= link_to("Next School", @school.next_school) if @school.next_school %>
```

routes:

```
get 'school' => 'schools#edit'
```

When I try pressing the buttons using this code, instead of sending me to where I want to go: "admin/schools/:id/edit", I get sent to: "school.:id" and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Is `get 'school' => 'schools#edit'` the only route in your `routes.rb` that is related to `school` or `schools`? Or are there other rules too?

Comment: Your code actually works for me. The only difference that I've made was ```resources :schools``` and ```<%= link_to("Previous School", edit_school_path(@school.previous_school)) if @school.previous_school %>
<%= link_to("Next School", edit_school_path(@school.next_school)) if @school.next_school %>```

Comment: Please show your `routes.rb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better use [resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) for describing routes:

```
resources :schools
```

Then your view should be

```
<%= link_to("Previous School", edit_school_path(@school.previous_school.id) if @school.previous_school %>
```